# Measuring the Earth-Moon distance on a scale of a coin Ø 24mm

Tags: trigonometry

A coin with 24mm in diameter, when it's 4 meters from you, looks about as big as the moon. The moon is 4000 km in diameter, and the goal is to measure the approximate distance between Earth and the moon.
How do I solve this with trigonometry and or unit cycle, with the values above?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made some effort.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: similar triangles. Diameter of coin relates to diameter of moon as distance from you to coin relates to the distance from you to the moon.